# ESC-POS-USB-NET Unable to access printer exception

Tags: epson, escpos, posprinter

I have an EPSON fiscal printer (FP 81 II)
I installed its drivers and now I'm able to print test document to the printer and it's ok.

The installed printer is the following

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to execute the simple code of the library

```
Printer printer = new Printer("Printer Name");
printer.TestPrinter();
printer.FullPaperCut();
printer.PrintDocument();
```

in Printer Name i tryed everithing:

- TM-T800F
- TM-T800F TM-T900F
- EPSON USB Controller for TM/BA/EU Printers

But nothing works, I have always the same Exception:

```
Unable to access printer : ...
```

Comment: Please search for materials from the links on this page. [FP-81II - Software & Document](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=prod&pcat=51&pid=3318) For examples. [Fiscal Printer User Manual (for Europe) Rev.V](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_doc&cid=5817&pcat=51&pid=3318), [Intelligent SDK for Windows (for Europe)](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5814&pcat=51&pid=3318), [EpsonFpSuite (for Europe)](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6115&pcat=51&pid=3318)

Answer (score 0):

From a previous experience I am thinking you may have a whitespace issue in the name. So copy and paste the name of the printer into your script.

1. Navigate to the "Printer properties" dialog
2. In the General tab copy the entire name.  (note there may be whitespace characters at the end of the printer name so be sure to capture those characters)
3. Paste the name into your test script.
4. Test

Good luck.